# How do I use a macro in the data portion of a resource script?

Tags: delphi, resources, macros, c++builder

I have the following macros header file (system.h),

```
#define rt_metadata 8000
#define dir_metadata "db\metadata"
```

and resource file (system.db.metadata.rc)

```
#include "system.h"
SY_ALLOWDATE   rt_metadata    db\metadata\SY.AllowDate.xml
```

How do I replace the **db\metadata** with **dir_metadata** in the resource file so that it will become something like **dir_metadata\SY.AllowDate.xml**?

Answer (score 1):

This is done by the resource compiler (BRCC32.EXE was Borland's version, and Microsoft had one as well).

Macros are done by a precompiler just before compiling; BRCC32 handled both the precompilation and compilation steps of converting an RC file into a binary RES file.

So you can get the macro converted by using the commandline resource compiler:

```
brcc32 yourresourcefile.rc
```

You can also define the macro on the commandline as well

```
brcc32 -dYOURMACRO=yourstring yourresourcefile.rc
```